# Get multiple boxes in background in ChartJs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Working with [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) and [annotations plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation), created the [codepen for reference](https://codepen.io/ghanendrap/pen/VwKPaXB).
There is a purple box in the background that encompasses the whole graph. However I want to limit it to from `12:36:28 pm` to `12:39:28 pm`
The box can be repeating, i.e., come multiple times, with width extending between different x indices.
Can someone see the codepen and guide how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include xScaleID: "x-axis-0", yScaleID: "y-axis-0"
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ9JC.png)